# How can I filter a R-markdown template header-includes to prevent asset version clashes?

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, header, r-markdown

I've set up a custom R-markdown template.html that uses bootstrap v4.1.0.

This was all well and good, until I added the following in the template html `head`:

```
$for(header-includes)$
  $header-includes$
$endfor$
```

(this comes from the default .html file and was needed to fix a template bug when loading plotly graphics) which loads bootstrap v3.3.5, among other things.

The problem is that now my formatting is doing funny things: menu bar misalignment and tiny font sizes. I think this is because of the 2 versions of bootstrap that are loaded, though bootstrap v4.1.0 is loaded second and should take priority.

I think I need to put a filter in the template `head`'s for loop so I can exclude the earlier version - but am not sure how. This problem has stumped me.

Alternatively, how can I check/define what is included in the `$header-includes$` part of the knit?

The current version of the package on [github](https://github.com/TelethonKids/biometrics) can be installed to see a reproducible example (I can't think of how to provide a reproducible example of the template here).

### update

Thanks to [this issue on github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1198) - if I add `theme: null` to the yaml header, my formatting issues are fixed (bootstrap v3.3.5 isn't loaded by default) - but I use `toc_float: true` to generate the bootstrap menu from the document headers, which apparently needs a theme:

> Error in (function (toc = FALSE, toc_depth = 3, toc_float = FALSE, number_sections = FALSE,  :    You must use a theme when specifying the 'toc_float' option

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around to this issue by removing the 3 lines:

```
$for(header-includes)$
  $header-includes$
$endfor$
```

from the html template and linking to the dependencies manually.

I was able to get these files by setting `self_contained: false`, which allows r-markdown to put all dependencies/external files into a directory; I copied these into my assets directory and referenced their path in the template.html file. I downloaded and linked to the updated versions where possible. Everything seems to be working as expected.

My issue is that this solution isn't robust. It will fail when future documents needs a dependency that isn't currently imported manually. Also, in the template's current form I have a bunch of plotly files that won't be needed for every piece of work I do.

Obviously, I can tailor the template for each project, but this kind of defeats the purpose of templating. Doesn't it? [Maybe r-markdown will be updated to include major updates to bootstrap.](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1260)